# Tor update 20 October fails to work

Tags: windows, update, troubleshooting

I opened Tor today and updated as advised. The installer downloads and opens, so I saved to desktop, but now Tor won't open. Running Windows 8.1, Comodo antivirus ( which has been adjusted to allow Tor to open)

Tor appears briefly in Task manager, then disappears. Other browsers including Firefox open as normal

Answer (score 2):

I am in the same boat. Have your seen this on the Tor site

> "Windows users that are affected by Tor Browser crashes might try to
>   avoid this problem by opening "`about:config`" and setting the
>   preference "`media.directshow.enabled`" to "`false`". This is a workaround
>   reported to help while the investigation is still on-going."

So enter `about:config` into the URL bar and accept the following warning. Now you see a list of settings. Enter `media.directshow.enabled` into the search and double-click on the entry to set it to `false`.

Comment: _"But I haven't a clue where this setting is"_ <-- Type `about:config` in the URL bar. You get a list of settings. Find the one named `media.directshow.enabled` and switch it from `true` to `false` by double clicking on it.

Comment: Thanks - however , when I click on the "Start Tor Browser" shortcut it  attempts to load but nothing happens.  Is there a registry entry I need to nuke or do I need call Tor from Firefox

Comment: I don't know, sorry. I don't run Windows. I just pointed out where that setting can be found and edited.

Comment: @Jobiwan thanks anyway your comment is useful as I would never have thought to look at the browser bar.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is actually quite well known and is being worked on. Most of us are encouraged to use Rapport antiPhishing software. However, this currently prevents Tor from running. This being looked at I am told.