# TBB fails to run on Windows 7

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, windows

I have installed TBB on Windows 7 Ultimate 64.  When I double click either the link or directly on the Firefox icon in the TBB map on my desktop (both normal and as admin) I can see in task scheduler that `firefox.exe` starts up and disappears after a few second.

I can't see any `Tor.exe` staring up. The result is that TBB won't start up. I tried downlaoding it several times to make sure TBB is not corrupted.

Comment: Please open the command line, navigate to the directory where you have the TBB (eg. `cd C:\Users\username\Desktop\TBB`) and run the startup script from there (just type the name of the script to run it). Copy and paste the output it gives you into this question.

Comment: Please have a look at https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/4389/88 Does this solve your problem?

Comment: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vfOI.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vfOI.png)
It's showing error to mine also