# Tor crashes while browsing

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, windows

I use Windows 7 64 bit on a premium computer running Windows 7 64 bit with 1 TB HDD 8GB RAM Core i7, so no reason for me to run into any problem. Tor installs itself on my desktop. However, when I try to go to a website it crashes after a few minutes.  I uninstalled and reinstalled Tor. If you have written a software fix to prevent this happening in future please tell me where I can download it and how I can install it on my Tor Browser. Thank you

Comment: Please launch Tor via the command line, browse until a crash happens, and then copy and paste the command line output here. If there is any error after the crash that you can see, please post that as well (also, yelling titles that don't provide any indication of what the problem is are not helpful).

Comment: Does the crash happen on different websites or just some (if so, which)? What TBB version do you use? Maybe you're affected by this bug: https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/4389/88

Comment: I went through the options, changed the home page and several tab settings, etc, which might have caused the crashes. So I deleted and reinstalled Tor browser (based on Firefox 52) fresh in a neutral location on my windows 8,1 pro C-drive, where I usually install portable apps (not in a system folder). So far, so good... I'll report back if I have further crashes. Apparently Tor is very temperamental, and as a newbie I have no idea what settings can be changed safely.